# FLUME IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN

Tags: java, flume, illegalstateexception, flume-ng, flume-twitter

I have written custom flume sink, named MySink, whose process method is indicated in the first snippet below. I am getting an IllegalStateException as follows (detailed stack trace is available in the 2nd snippet below):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when
>   transaction is OPEN!

**QUESTION:** I have followed the KafkaSink and similar existing sink implementations in flume code base while writing the process method and I am applying the very same transaction handling logic with those exiting sinks. Could you please tell me what is wrong in my process method here? How can I fix the problem?

**PROCESS method (I have marked where the exception is thrown):**

```
@Override
public Status process() throws EventDeliveryException {
    Status status = Status.READY;
    Channel ch = getChannel();
    Transaction txn = ch.getTransaction();
    Event event = null;

    try {
        LOG.info(getName() + " BEFORE txn.begin()");
    //!!!! EXCEPTION IS THROWN in the following LINE !!!!!!
        txn.begin();
        LOG.info(getName() + " AFTER txn.begin()");
        LOG.info(getName() + " BEFORE ch.take()");
        event = ch.take();
        LOG.info(getName() + " AFTER ch.take()");

        if (event == null) {
            // No event found, request back-off semantics from the sink runner
            LOG.info(getName() + " - EVENT is null! ");
            return Status.BACKOFF;
        }

        Map<String, String> keyValueMapInTheMessage = event.getHeaders();
        if (!keyValueMapInTheMessage.isEmpty()) {
            mDBWriter.insertDataToDB(keyValueMapInTheMessage);
        }

        LOG.info(getName() + " - EVENT: " + EventHelper.dumpEvent(event));
        if (txn != null) {
            txn.commit();                
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String errMsg = getName() + " - Failed to publish events. Exception: ";
        LOG.info(errMsg);
        status = Status.BACKOFF;
        if (txn != null) {
            try {
                txn.rollback();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.info(getName() + " - EVENT: " + EventHelper.dumpEvent(event));
                throw Throwables.propagate(e);
            }
        }
        throw new EventDeliveryException(errMsg, ex);
    } finally {
        if (txn != null) {
            txn.close();
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

**EXCEPTION STACK:**

```
2016-01-22 14:01:15,440 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:160)]  

Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
```

> ```
> org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: MySink - Failed to publish events.
> Exception:    at com.XYZ.flume.maprdb.MySink.process(MySink.java:116)
> ```

```
at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: begin() called when transaction is OPEN!
> ```

```
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.begin(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:131)
at com.XYZ.flume.maprdb.MySink.process(MySink.java:82)
... 3 more
```

Comment: I have discovered where the problem originates. I am using MapR's OJAI API to store the data the sink is receiving and it looks the exception disappears if I remove the line where I store data, that is:

mDBWriter.insertDataToDB(keyValueMapInTheMessage);

I am investigating what is the thing in this OJAI API that causes the transaction to get messed up.

Comment: I have a similar issue with a custom sink. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
if (event == null) {
    // No event found, request back-off semantics from the sink runner
    LOG.info(getName() + " - EVENT is null! ");
    return Status.BACKOFF;
 }
```

this code causes this problem. when event is null, you just return it.however, the correct way is to commit or rollback.a transaction should go through three stages: begin, commit or rollback, finally close.we can see the following source code to find how it implements.

BasicChannelSemantics：

```html
  public Transaction getTransaction() {

    if (!initialized) {
      synchronized (this) {
        if (!initialized) {
          initialize();
          initialized = true;
        }
      }
    }

    BasicTransactionSemantics transaction = currentTransaction.get();
    if (transaction == null || transaction.getState().equals(
            BasicTransactionSemantics.State.CLOSED)) {
      transaction = createTransaction();
      currentTransaction.set(transaction);
    }
    return transaction;
  }
```

when currentTransaction is null or its State is close, channel will create a new one, otherwise return the old one. this exception does not happen immediately. when the first time execute the process method, you get a new transaction, but the event is null, you just return and finally close, the close method does not work because of its implement.so the second time execute the process method, you don't get a new transaction, it is the old one.the following code is about how transaction implement.

BasicTransactionSemantics:

```html
  protected BasicTransactionSemantics() {
    state = State.NEW;
    initialThreadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
  }
  
  public void begin() {
    Preconditions.checkState(Thread.currentThread().getId() == initialThreadId,
        "begin() called from different thread than getTransaction()!");
    Preconditions.checkState(state.equals(State.NEW),
        "begin() called when transaction is " + state + "!");

    try {
      doBegin();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      throw new ChannelException(e.toString(), e);
    }
    state = State.OPEN;
  }

  public void commit() {
    Preconditions.checkState(Thread.currentThread().getId() == initialThreadId,
        "commit() called from different thread than getTransaction()!");
    Preconditions.checkState(state.equals(State.OPEN),
        "commit() called when transaction is %s!", state);

    try {
      doCommit();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      throw new ChannelException(e.toString(), e);
    }
    state = State.COMPLETED;
  }

 public void rollback() {
    Preconditions.checkState(Thread.currentThread().getId() == initialThreadId,
        "rollback() called from different thread than getTransaction()!");
    Preconditions.checkState(state.equals(State.OPEN),
        "rollback() called when transaction is %s!", state);

    state = State.COMPLETED;
    try {
      doRollback();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      throw new ChannelException(e.toString(), e);
    }
  }
  
 public void close() {
    Preconditions.checkState(Thread.currentThread().getId() == initialThreadId,
        "close() called from different thread than getTransaction()!");
    Preconditions.checkState(
            state.equals(State.NEW) || state.equals(State.COMPLETED),
            "close() called when transaction is %s"
            + " - you must either commit or rollback first", state);

    state = State.CLOSED;
    doClose();
  }
```

when create, the state is new.

when begin, the state must be new, then state become open.

when commit or rollback, the state must be open, then state  become complete.

when close, the state must be complete, then state become close.

so when you execute the close method in a right way, the next time you will get a new transaction, otherwise the old one which state must not be new, so you can't execute transaction.begin(), it needs a new one.